# Azure Datafactory Copy activity from SAP system on Unpartitioned data

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, sap

How to read TetaByte of data from On-prem SAP system into Azure blob storage very fastly using Azure datafactory?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a help site for programming questions. Please have a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-table?tabs=data-factory)

MSFT has provided detailed documentation on ADF connectivity with SAP. You can first create a **linked service** to SAP, create a **Dataset** and use that dataset as **Source** in a **Copy Activity**

Comment: I think the question is more about data volume and transfer speed, not how to connect (unless if each part of the sentence is one question, but Stack Overflow requires limiting to one question per question).